# error in htaccess for redirecting url in php

Tags: .htaccess

i have following code but redirection is not working plz help

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ product.php?name=$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

it is not reditrecting to `product.php`

Comment: Is mod_rewrite actually enabled?

Comment: thanks for replying sir

Comment: sir this i have only this code in my htacess file 
plz give me the solution sir

Answer (score 0):

I modifyed the Link now and think this should work.
I tested it on my local server and it works.

```
RewriteRule ^([/products]+)/(.*)$ product.php?name=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

On my installation, i work on a sub dir so it can be that the param should be $2 instead of $1

It have also an impact if you use

```
 href"hello.com....."
```

or

```
href="http://hello.com....."
```

Comment: This mean that your product.php should be located in the root directory. If not you net to add the directory  /yourDirectory/ before product.php,

Comment: this code was previoudly working perfectly sir but sudenly it is not working . can you tell me solutions sir plz help

Comment: @ Rahul Kumar what kind of error do you get? did you had a look in the error_log ? or if you heve rewrite_log ?

Comment: sir thanku for ur valable time.. sir this is my anchor tag

Comment: $siteurl="hello.com/";
<a href="<?php echo $siteurl ;?>products/<?php echo Encode($r2['name']);?>"> where $r2['name']='dummy'

it shoud be redirect to hello.com/product.php?name="dummy";

Comment: @Rahul Kumar it have also an impact if you use <a href"hello.com....."> or <a href"http://hello.com.....">

Comment: SIR THE SAME CODE WAS WORKING ON THE LIVE SITE BUT WHY IT IS NOT WORKING NOW I HAVNT MADE ANY CHANGE

Comment: THIS IS CODE
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ product.php?name=$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ product.php?name=$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>

Comment: SIR ACTULLY THERE IS NO ANY ERROR IN CODE.HTacess file is not working that is main issue

Comment: is mod rewite activated ? with "a2enmod rewrite" you can check it